# .net core cascading dropdownlist returns undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I do not understand why it's undefined.
in the controller, Create Action is set the categories dropdownlist.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new TechnicialSpecsViewModel();

    List<Product> categories = _productService.GetAllParents();
    model.CategoryList = (from i in categories
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Value = i.Id.ToString(),
                              Text = i.Name
                          }).ToList();
    model.CategoryList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "Select", Selected = true });

    return View(model);
}
```

and if I pick an option from the category dropdown, send the category id to ProductList action. so I can get the list of products where categoryId == id

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult ProductList(int id)
 {
     List<Product> products = _productService.GetByParent(id);
     return Json(new SelectList(products, "Id", "Name"));
 }
```

its perfect, but when I looked to products dropdown, it seems all undefined.

here is my function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CategoryId").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var productId = $("#ProductId");
            productId.empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/TechnicialSpecs/ProductList',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 'id': id },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, option) {
                        productId.append('<option value=' + option.Value + '> ' + option.Text + ' </option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and view,

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, Model.CategoryList, new { @class = "bs-select form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">  
        <select id="ProductId" name="ProductId" asp-for="Product" asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Name"))"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

also, both models are of the same type, I really don't understand why these undefined.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Controller Method should be as follows:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ProductList(int id)
{
     List<Product> products = _productService.GetByParent(id);
     return Json(products);
}
```

**Your View should be as follows:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId, Model.CategoryList, new { @class = "bs-select form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">  
        <select id="ProductId" name="ProductId" asp-for="Product"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Then your Ajax Method should be as follows:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CategoryId").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/TechnicialSpecs/ProductList',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: id },
                success: function (data) {
                    var options = '';
                    $.each(data, function () {
                    options += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + 
                    this.name+ '</option>';
                    });
                    $("#ProductId").prop('disabled', false).html(options);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope it will now work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small change from option.Value to option.value and option.Text to option.text you can also debug in console by pressing f12 in browser and check the value of option.Value and option.Text here Value and Text are undefined.